# Changing strings into numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner in python and I have a large array to process and one of the columns (loan_status) has all entries as a characters (not numbers) and i would like to change them into numbers. There are different type of entries but basically i am only interested in "fully paid" and "current" and i would like to change them into 1 and all other entries to 0.

```
1 import numpy as np
2 import pandas as pd
3
4 data_file = pd.read_csv('loan.csv')
5 loan_stat = data_file.loan_status
6 for i in range(len(loan_stat)):
7    if loan_stat[i]=='Fully Paid':
8        loan_stat[i]=1
9    elif loan_stat[i]=='Current':
10        loan_stat[i]=1
11    else:
12        loan_stat[i]=0
13
14 print(loan_stat)
```

i get such error when i execute " value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame". the error refers to lines 8,10,12.

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: Have you tried: `df.loan_stat = df.loan_stat.map({'Fully Paid': 1, 'Current': 1}`) ?

Comment: or the `replace` function?

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40214434/6779509) for understanding the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, implementing an if-else on a pandas series, is probably using `np.where`:

```
5 data_file['loan_status'] = np.where(data_file['loan_status'].isin(['Fully Paid', 'Current']), 1, 0)
6 print(data_file['loan_status'])
```

Note that this excludes the assignment

```
loan_stat = data_file.loan_status
```

operating on the assumption that you want to modify the column `data_file['loan_status']` in the dataframe.

If you instead want to get a separate series with a 'Fully Paid'/'Current' indicator variable just while avoiding the `SettingWithCopyWarning` (which is elaborated on in @Parth Chaudhary's excellent link), then

```
5 loan_stat = np.where(data_file['loan_status'].isin(['Fully Paid', 'Current']), 1, 0)
```

would do it.

Alternatively, just replacing your line #5 with

```
5 loan_stat = data_file.loan_status.copy()
```

will also avoid the issue that triggers the warning, though I wouldn't recommend it, if only because looping over a pandas series/dataframe or a numpy array when you have other options is usually a lot slower.

Comment: Thank you!! I used your np.where solution and it works perfectly although I still don't quite get why I got the error in my code in the first place. I will try to understand that link from @Parth Chaudhary. Thank you one more time

Answer (score 0):

You can create another list for storing 0's and 1's

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_file = pd.read_csv('loan.csv')
loan_stat = data_file.loan_status
loan_n=[]
for i in range(len(loan_stat)):
   if loan_stat[i]=='Fully Paid':
       #loan_stat[i]=1
       loan_n.append(1)
   elif loan_stat[i]=='Current':
        #loan_stat[i]=1
        loan_n.append(1)
   else:
        #loan_stat[i]=0
        loan_n.append(0)

print(loan_n)
```